# Date functions using tableau

Tags: function, date, tableau-desktop

I have to convert date using tableau functions "FY23Q1" to "2023-Q1"

Example
DATE
FY23Q1
FY23Q2
FY23Q3

To be updated as
2023-Q1
2023-Q2
2023-Q3

Answer (score 1):

I think your date field is string type.("FY23Q1")
If your dates are not less than 2000, you can create a calculation like this:

```
REPLACE(LEFT([YourData],4)+"-"+RIGHT([YourData],2),"FY","20")
```